# How to change the format of an XML for importing into WordPress?

Tags: xml, wordpress

Now I have a large amount of content extracted from an unknown CMS. What I need to do is to change the format of this XML so I can import those posts into my new WordPress website.

What's the fast and easy method to do this? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't know your old CMS, get a sample XML from Wordpress to see the required format. Compare yours to the latter and build a script that parses the data and writes it again in the WP format. Probably not fast (neither easy), but I guess it's the only thing you could do.

Comment: @JordiNebot Thanks for your help mate. I just found a plugin called "WP All Import". Incredibly easy to import any XML into WordPress. I can't be more happy with that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin called WP All Import which can import any XML into WordPress. Need to pay for pro-functions, but incredibly easy to use!